# F-measure for document clustering evaluation - NaN

Tags: clustering, data-mining, measurement

I'm developing the Java application for text document clustering, and I'm researching some evaluation methods. I implemented F-measure (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score), but I have a problem - the returned value is NaN. It happens where a cluster doesn't contain any data from a specific category - precision and recall are equal to zero. How should I handle this situation - F-measure in that case should be zero as well? I will be very grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: I would just have an if statement that checks if both the precision and recall are zero and set the F-score to zero when that occurs.

**Long answer**:
In a rigorous mathematical sense, the F1-score is defined such that if the precision and recall are both zero, the F1-score is undefined:
$$
F1=2\cdot\frac{precision \cdot recall}{precision+recall}.
$$

You could perhaps justify setting F1 to zero by arguing that you are only sampling the true population and as precision and recall approach a small value, $\epsilon$, the numerator approaches zero faster than the denominator since it goes like $\frac{\epsilon^{2}}{\epsilon}=\epsilon$~0.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one F-measure around in the sense that it is computed on different data.

For evaluating cluster analysis, it seems to be most common to compute the F-measure on **pairs of objects**, and on the complete data set, not on single clusters.

See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725263/computing-f-measure-for-clustering

Comment: I know, I'm calculating a weighted mean of F-measures for all clusters later.

Comment: Precision and recall for individual clusters aren't clearly defined or sensible, that is the problem you are running into.